# How to use iOS sounds for push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, system-sounds

Apps like Whatsapp and Telegram provide a list of notification sounds which the user can set. For eg. in both Whatsapp and Telegram the list of sounds is divided into 2 categories: Alert Tones (Default, None, Aurora, Bamboo....) and Classic(Bell, Boing, Glass....). These sounds are also present in iPhone sound settings. So do these apps fetch these sounds from system?
I am building an iOS app in which I want to provide the same sound list as above so that user can choose the notification sound from that list.
How to fetch these list of sounds to display to the user?

Comment: Whatever sound we provide. Mostly we provide by default sound.

Comment: How do fetch these default sound list?

Comment: We dont fetch default sounds. We have option for 2 or 3 sounds.

Comment: So you have saved some sound files in your xcode project folder which you display it to the user?